# MVC 3 EditorFor lists while specifying a template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am late to the game. i am struggling with EditorFor.

Instead of using the template to display the name of the entity in a textbox, the name is written to screen. It appears to be writing the first property of the object as in my real project a guid is being written.

How can I use the editorfor while specifying the template?

**Home Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
            HomeModel homeModel = new HomeModel();
            homeModel.RoomModels = new List<RoomModel>();
            homeModel.RoomModels.Add(new RoomModel() { RoomName = "Room-1" });
            homeModel.RoomModels.Add(new RoomModel() { RoomName = "Room-2" });
            homeModel.RoomModels.Add(new RoomModel() { RoomName = "Room-3" });

            return View(homeModel);
    }
```

**Home Model**

```
public class HomeModel
    {
        public List<RoomModel> RoomModels { get; set; }
    }
```

**Room Model**

```
public class RoomModel
{
    public string RoomName { get; set; }
}
```

**/Views/Home/Index.cshtml**

```
@model MVC.Temp.Models.Home.HomeModel

<h1>Home</h1>
<div id="RoomModels">
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.RoomModels, "_RoomModelEditor")
</div>
```

**/Views/Home/_RoomModelEditor.cshtml**

```
@model MVC.Temp.Models.Home.RoomModel
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.RoomName)
```

**Current Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put your editor template in directory called **EditorTemplates**. So the correct path should be the following:

```
/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/_RoomModelEditor.cshtml
```

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407414%28v=vs.98%29.aspx):

> If a template whose name matches the templateName parameter is found
>   in the controller's EditorTemplates folder, that template is used to
>   render the expression. If a template is not found in the controller's
>   EditorTemplates folder, the Views\Shared\EditorTemplates folder is
>   searched for a template that matches the name of the templateName
>   parameter. If no template is found, the default template is used.

Comment: Is there any way to specify a full path? I have two areas and one area needs to use the other areas editortemplate. So far I have tried to the overload specifying the full path on the EditorFor method. (usually this works with html.renderpartial). `"~/Areas/Area1/Views/Other/EditorTemplates/EditModel.cshtml"`

Comment: If you want to use the same editortemplate from multiple contollers/areas you have to put in the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` as the documentation states also in my answer. The framework first look in the controllers EditorTemplates and then in the `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates` and that is it. There is no way specify absolute paths for editor templates.

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder under `/Views/Home` called `EditorTemplates`.  Call your template `RoomModel.cshtml`.

So the full template name is `/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/RoomModel.cshtml`.

Using the name of the class for the name of the editor template means that whenever you do `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.RoomModels)` it will use your editor template automatically.

**Update**

If you have multiple controllers with views that need to shared the same editor template then put your template in `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates`.

Comment: @Valamas - except that I just reread your comment and noticed the use of Areas.  I haven't used areas before, so I don't know if it's possible to share templates like this.

Comment: thanks. I guess i will have to work with that. I am not a fan of the "shared" views unless they are truly shared. Like layouts. Otherwise I always assign a view to live somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is that you are passing a `List<RoomModel>` instead of a `RoomModel`.

You should change your EditorTemplate to accept a List... or do a Foreach in your view displaying each RoomModel.